# どこかでなろうたんですか。meaning?

Tags: grammar, dialects, kansai-ben

someone is amazed by his friend's ability of dancing well so he asked him 
どこかでなろうたんですか

and his friend replied 
ええ、坂本さんに教えてもらいました。彼、ダンスがとくいなんです。

I don't get the meaning "なろうたんですか” here ?

Answer (score 7):

「なろうた」 is how Kansai people say 「ならった/習った」 ("learned").

> 「どこかでなろうたんですか。」

thus means:

> "Did you learn it someplace?"

Other examples of this Kansaiism:

・わらった ⇒ わろうた (laughed)

・あらった ⇒ あろうた (washed)

・もらった ⇒ もろうた (received)